# ASP.NET Core Serilog not pushing property to its custom column

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this setup in `appsettings.json` for my Serilog installation

```
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": "Information",
  "Enrich": [ "LogUserName" ],
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Critical"
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "MSSqlServer",
      "Args": {
        "connectionString": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Apple;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;,
        "schemaName": "Apple",
        "tableName": "EventLogs",
        "columnOptionsSection": {
          "customColumns": [
            {
              "ColumnName": "UserName",
              "DataType": "nvarchar",
              "DataLength": 256,
              "AllowNull": true
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

I also have a custom enricher called `LogUserName` that is supposed to add the users username to a column called `UserName` in the db.

This is the enricher:

```
public class LogUserName
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public LogUserName(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", context.User.Identity.Name);
        await next(context);
        //return next(context);
    }
}
```

I have added `.Enrich.FromLogContext()` to my `Program.cs`.

So far I am able to see the `UserName` in the property tag but I am unable to push it to the column.

EDIT:

I use this model for my logs to the database:

```
public class EventLogs
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Properties { get; set; }
    public string LogEvent { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string MessageTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you confirm if the context.User.Identity.Name has a value?

Comment: Yes it does. I have pushed a string and it has appeared

Comment: Do me a huge favor and set "AllowNull": true to false and run your code again to push the property

Comment: I just set it to false. It doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: I have added my model to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Your enricher isn't valid. You're mixing up two concepts. Adding a property to the log context is not the same as creating an actual enricher. An actual enricher should implement ILogEventEnricher, as shown in [this example](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-enrichers-environment/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Enrichers.Environment/Enrichers/MachineNameEnricher.cs).

What you actually created is ASP.NET Middleware. The LogContext.PushProprety returns an IDisposable and should be wrapped in a using statement, and then anything inside the using statement block should have the log context with the additional property. Like shown in [the documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment).

One way to fix this is to remove `LogUserName` from your enrichers configuration. Then change your middleware to this:

```
public class LogUserNameMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public LogUserNameMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        using(LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", context.User.Identity.Name))
        {
            await next(context);
        }       
    }
}
```

Note you'll need tell ASP.NET Core about the Middleware, if you haven't already done so.

```
public static class LogUserNameMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseLogUserNameMiddleware(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<LogUserNameMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

and in the Startup.Configure method, you can add the middleware to your pipeline:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseLogUserNameMiddleware();
        //your other middleware
    }
}
```

Note, you may want to clean up your middleware to handle if there isn't a logged in user, so you don't get a NullReferenceException.