# Azure App Insights - How to add Custom Property to Custom Events in App insights using serilog?

Tags: azure-application-insights, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

Custom Property is not found in upstream classes (middleware, api layer) after pushing it in the downstream class (infrastructure layer) like below.

```
public async Task<T> GetFromCacheAsync<T>(string key) where T: class
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var cachedResponse = await _distributedCache.GetStringAsync(key);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cachedResponse)) { return null; }
    LogContext.PushProperty(IS_CACHED_RESPONSE, "True");
    Log.Information($"Fetched the response from azure cache for redis with Cache Key: {key} in Time: {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(cachedResponse);
}
```

###### App Insight Logs Where Custom property is pushed

[image: App Insight Logs Where Custom property is pushed]

###### App Insight Logs Where Custom property is not found within same operationID/RequestId

[image: App Insight Logs Where Custom property is not found within same operationID/RequestId]

Comment: I Hope you are using the **`IS_CACHED_RESPONSE`** property inside the middleware block.
If not, you can use in a Middleware block. Refer to the mason [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53890138/15997690) solution.

Comment: @DelliganeshSevanesan The middleware code is in Api layer, my code is in infra structure layer where I would know the value of IS_CACHED_RESPONSE  ( if i got the response from cache or not).